# What is the equivalent __LINE__ (php) in bash ?

Tags: bash

Running Ubuntu16.04 I would like to display in the terminal the line number in a running bash script.

It would be something like this example if it was in php:

```
echo "Installing NGINX. Line: ".__LINE__
```

How could I translate it to bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash` you can use the variable `$LINENO` for this purpose:

```
echo Installing NGINX. Line: $LINENO
```

`$LINENO` holds the current line number, see `man bash`:

> LINENO
>   Each time this parameter is referenced, the shell substitutes a
>   decimal number representing the current
>             sequential  line  number  (starting with 1) within a script or function.  When not in a script or func‐
>             tion, the value substituted is not guaranteed to be meaningful.  If LINENO is unset, it loses its  spe‐
>             cial properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

#### Example

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo $LINENO; echo $LINENO

echo $LINENO
```

When executed this script prints:

```
2
2
4
```